# re.search and 'in' not detecting substring in string

Tags: python, regex

In my project, I need to find the next instance of a date in the file I've parsed using bs4. I extracted the date initially using regex, and to find the next instance I go element by element and try to detect the date substring I extracted in those elements (nodes). The date appears in the exact form as how it was extracted, but it isn't being detected.

Here are the two variations on the if statement I'm trying to call it in:

`if re.search(second_date.strip().lower(), node.text.strip().lower()):`

and

`if second_date.strip().lower() in node.text.strip().lower():`

I was concerned maybe it was an issue with special characters or non-breaking spaces or some other nonsense, and saw similar suggestings on other posts on the site, so I also did this when reading the file, but it didn't result in any changes:

```
with open(filepath, 'r', encoding = "utf-8", errors = "ignore") as file:
        content = file.read().replace("&nbsp;", ' ').replace("\xa0", ' ').replace('\u00a0', ' ').replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```

When printing the values I used in my If statements, this is what I get (for the node it should be detecting):

print(second_date.strip().lower()) -> december 31, 2022

print(node.text.strip().lower()) -> ares capital corporation and subsidiariesconsolidated schedule of investmentsas of december 31, 2022 (dollar amounts in millions)

I've browsed similar issues by others on the site, but it seems that the general solution has been to deal with things such as non-breaking spaces, but I've had no such luck yet.

Comment: Try printing the `repr()` of these strings, rather than the strings themselves - that will make any non-printable characters visible.

Comment: Don't use `re.search()` to search for fixed strings, unless you call `re.escape()` to escape all the special characters.

Comment: It's not just non-printable chatacters that may cause problems: there's also some non-ascii punctation marks and whatnot that aren't what they seem to be when you print them.

Comment: Understood, I'll stick with using 'in' then. Is there a good/comprehensive way to filter out non-printable characters AND non-ascii punctuation marks that could be causing issues (replace them with a space)?